# Filter documents by considering DateTime attribute in nested object array

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, .net-core

**This is the document view**

```
{
"_id": "Binary('mDwdHszhpUOjNtsr9m2e0w==', 3)",
"DocName": "doc1"
"Dates":[
  {
    "_id": "66634"
    "StartTime": "2021-11-18T07:30:00.000+00:00"
  },
  {
    "_id": "66259"
    "StartTime": "2021-11-20T01:00:00.000+00:00"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm working with .netcore and mongodb and I need to filter all the documents based on a date ranges and a single date.

**This is the document class**

```
public class Documents: BaseEntity
    {
        public string DocName { get; set; }
        
        public List<Dates> Dates { get; set; }
        
}
```

**This is the Dates class**

```
public class Dates : ValueObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    }
```

since I'm new to .netcore I tried several methods as below.

```
var builder = Builders<Documents>.Filter;
// var builder2 = Builders<Dates>.Filter;
var filter = (FilterDefinition<Documents>)null;
if(dateRange == "Today"){ // when getting a single date (stucked in this part)

    filter = builder.Where(a => a.Dates.Any(d => d.StartTime == todaysDate));  //no results
    filter = builder.Where(a => a.Dates.Equals(d => d.StartTime, todaysDate)); //error- (Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type)

}
else{ // when getting a date range (working properly)
    filter = builder.Where(a => a.Dates.Any(date => date.StartTime >= fromDate));
    if (toDate != null) {
        filter = filter & builder.Where(a => a.Dates.Any(date => date.StartTime <= toDate));}
    }
}
```

Please guide me to get this solved. Thanks in advance.